# child property from parent Promise

Tags: lit-element, lit

I want to create a navigation component for my project. The `shell` fetches a json with chapter info, these are passed to `nav-element`, which recursively calls itself to render the navigation tree.

shell.js

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit-element';
import {until} from 'lit-html/directives/until.js';
import './nav-element.js';

export class Shell extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      configjson : { type: Array }
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.configjson = fetch('./src/convertjson_test.json').then(res => res.json());
  }

  render() {
    return html`
        <main>
            some content
            <nav-element .chapters=${until(this.configjson, [])} root></nav-element>
        </main>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('shell', Shell);
```

nav-element.js

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit-element';
import {until} from 'lit-html/directives/until.js';
import {repeat} from 'lit-html/directives/repeat.js';

export class NavElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
        chapters: {type: Array},
        root: {type: Boolean} //to mark the root node
    };
  }

  static get styles() {
    return css`
        .navheader {
            display: none;
        }

        .navheader[active] {
            display: block;
        }
    `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
        <div class="navHeader" ?active="${this.root}">header</div>
        ${until(repeat(this.chapters, (chapter) => chapter.pos, (chapter) => html`<div>${chapter.n}<nav-element .chapters=${chapter.c}></nav-element></div>`))}
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('nav-element', NavElement);
```

The problem is, that the `configjson` Promise is passed as property and not yet resolved by the time the `nav-element` is called, so i get the error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.chapters is undefined`

Searched all `lit-element` and `lit-html` documentation, the `until` directive resolved the issue in the `shell`, but not in the `nav-element`.
The same coding pattern worked fine in `Polymer 2` (&3, although with ajax instead of fetch). Does anyone know how to solve this using lit-element only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a time frame between the construction of `NavElement` and the assignment of the `chapters` property where `chapters` is `undefined`. It might be safe to initialize `chapters` in the component itself rather than in `Shell`'s `until` directive, or at least provide a fallback value in the template:

```js
export class NavElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
        chapters: {type: Array},
        // ...
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.chapters = [];
  }

  // or

  render() {
    return html`
      ...
      ${repeat(this.chapters || [], chapter => ...)}
    `;
  }
}
```

Also, you've (correctly) declared the `chapters` property as an `Array` but you're wrapping the `repeat` directive in an `until` (as if it was a `Promise` I guess?). Here there are two things going on:

- the `repeat()` call returns a `DirectiveFn` and not a `Promise` like `until` expects. If `chapters` was a `Promise`, the correct way to combine `until` and `repeat` would have been:

  ```js
  until(
    this.chaptersPromise.then(chapters => repeat(chapters, chapter => html`...`)),
    html`Loading...`,
  )
  ```

  but...
- `chapters` is not a `Promise`: the `until` call in the parent component resolves it and passes the result.

As for the `Shell` component: `until` used in this way should work, however its intended use is to

> Render placeholder content until the final content is available
>
> [from [lit-html docs](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#until)]

To make the most of it, use it to temporarily render a loading template instead of `<nav-element>`:

```js
render() {
  return html`
    ${until(
      this.configJson.then(chapters => html`<nav-element .chapters=${chapters}></nav-element>`),
      html`Loading chapters`,
    )}
  `;
}
```

Also, not a big deal, but here the `configJson` property is declared as an `Array` but is actually a `Promise`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, the trick with the conditional and the empty array works great!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)